# Vuew and webpack lazy loading. Where is chunk file defined?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, lazy-loading

With vuejs, https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/lazy-loading.html.

I ran the example code.

In the example with lazy-loading,  where is this 0.chunk.js and 1.chunk.js is defined?

[image]

the webpack document says "non-entry chunk files" but how do we define this chunk files. I looked at the vue-router example code, but could not figure it out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can able find lazyloading defnition in `/examples/webpack.config.js`, In [github](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/1a6113f98bd57b4bc837598262c827d1443bacbc/examples/webpack.config.js#L22). In output configuration its configured as follows

```
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '__build__'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',
    publicPath: '/__build__/'
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

These chunks are normally defined in your `js/manifest.js` file, and are generated by webpack for this purpose.

in mine it looks like this (after pretty printing)

```
o.src = a.p + "js/" + e + "." + {
    0: "796f1d0e67b998e17b3f",
    1: "81d71d5e62996e7658f9",
    2: "4775738f0618fa75e735",
    3: "fd3c35ef3f5142e14115",
    4: "7ad17212637dbc558b8a",
    ...
}[e] + ".js";
```

These chunks are built based off of your router file. You should also notice in the js folder it has `e.chunkID.js` which corresponds to that list.